# How do I exit the IIS Express worker process without getting confirmation message?

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-express

Every time I right-click my IIS Express worker process to exit, I receive the following confirmation message: "Are you sure you want to stop all the worker processes and exit?"

[image: Are you sure you want to stop all the worker processes and exit?]

Is there a setting somewhere that will allow me to turn off this confirmation message?

Comment: How did you launch it? Use /systray:false so no tray icon will be there.

Comment: Launched web application via IE through Visual Studio and IIS Express automatically started.

Comment: Then VS automatically handles the processes for you, why do you want to manually control that? Any specific issue you met?

Comment: @LexLi - Yes, my aspx.vb page isn't always seeing changes I make to the code if I don't exit the worker process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not. But you can write a batch file to automate the termination.

```
taskkill /im "iisexpress.exe"
```